# How to use ComputeHash in flutter

Tags: c#, asp.net, flutter, dart, hash

everyone I'm working on convert a C# Hash function to a piece of code using dart, but I figure out that the result of those two functions (the original function with C# and my current function with flutter) are not the same.

after debugging I find that the problem is on converting ComputeHash method to flutter (I can't find something like it).

the original function:

```
private static String sign(String data, String secretKey) {
            UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] keyByte = encoding.GetBytes(secretKey);
            HMACSHA256 hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(keyByte);
            
            byte[] messageBytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
            var res = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes));
 }
```

The flutter function:

```
  String sign(String data, String secretKey) {
    List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(_SECRET_KEY);
    var hmacSha256 = Hmac(sha256, bytes);

    List<int> messageBytes = utf8.encode(data);
    var code = hmacSha256.convert(messageBytes).bytes; // the problem starting here the result of code function is different comparing with hmacsha256.ComputeHash(messageBytes)
    print(base64Encode(code));
  }
```

NB: I'm using crypto [package](https://pub.dev/packages/crypto).

Comment: For those of us without C# development tools, it might help to provide examples with sample inputs and the desired outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue... my problem was the way that the secret key was being encoded. My original C# service is using "Convert.FromBase64String"... the solution was:

C#

```
var secretKeyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(_secretKey);

            byte[] signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureRawData);

            using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyByteArray))
            {
                byte[] signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signature);
                string requestSignatureBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);
                //Setting the values in the Authorization header using custom scheme (amx)
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("hmac", string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", _applicationId, requestSignatureBase64String, nonce, requestTimeStamp));
        }
```

Dart:

```
final keyBytes = base64Decode(key);
  final dataBytes = utf8.encode(data);

  final hmacBytes = Hmac(sha256, keyBytes).convert(dataBytes).bytes;
  final hmacBase64 = base64Encode(hmacBytes);

  return hmacBase64;
```